# Are there cryptographic hash functions with homomorphic properties?

Tags: hash, hash-tree

Are there cryptographic hash functions that have homomorphism-like properties?

E.g. satisfying following relation $h(a || b) = h(a) · h(b)$, where $h(x)$ is hash function itself, $x || y$ is concatenation and $x · y$ is some hash-specific combination function making single hash given two of them. If that makes any difference, it can be also assumed $a$ and $b$ are of equal length, and $h(x)$ is expected to produce hash sums of same length regardless of $x$.

I can think of basic, non-cryptographic example — $h(x)$ can be plain arithmetic sum of character codes modulo 256, and $x · y := (x + y) \bmod 256$, so

$$ h(\texttt{"foo"}) = (102 + 111 + 111) \bmod 256 = 68 $$
 $$ h(\texttt{"bar"}) = (98 + 97 + 114) \bmod 256 = 53 $$
 $$ h(\texttt{"foobar"}) = (102 + 111 + 111 + 98 + 97 + 114) \bmod 256 = 121 $$
 $$ h(\texttt{"foo"}) · h(\texttt{"bar"}) = (68 + 53) \bmod 256 = 121 $$

So, is there something similar, but with high collision resistance?

Comment: The normal definition of "distributive" is that two operations + and * share it if A*(B+C) = (A*B) + (A*C), for all A, B, C.  You might want to clarify what property you are looking for.  Also, I suspect that any such property would make it easier to find hash collisions; what is the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: Maybe the author means some sort of homomorphism?

Comment: @poncho, yes, distributive properties like you describe will likely to reduce the collision security level (in bits) by the factor of 2 or so.

Comment: Yes, "homomorphic" property is the right word.

Comment: We already have questions here that provide lots of information on this subject.  Simply searching on "homomorphic hash" in the search bar at the upper right turned up the following: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/6497/351, http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8074/351, http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12719/351.  In the future, you might want to do a bit of research before asking, to help you ask a more informed question.

Comment: [$SL_2$ homomorphic hash functions: worst case to average case reduction and short collision search](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.5646). Des. Codes Cryptogr. (2016)

Answer (score 6):

My understanding is that, for the even more special case where `a` and `b` are not only of equal length but some power of two times a fixed block size, all hash tree systems (also called a [Merkle tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) system or a [binary hash chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/hash_chain#Binary_hash_chains)) meet your criteria.

> E.g. satisfying following relation `h(a || b) = h(a) · h(b)`, where
>   `h(x)` is hash function itself, `x || y` is concatenation and `x · y`
>   is some hash-specific combination function making single hash given
>   two of them.

In particular, the hash specified by the Tree Hash EXchange format (THEX) spec
uses the hash-specific combination function `x · y == SHA1( 0x00 || x || y )`.
whenever the underlying pieces of text `a` and `b` are the same length and are both some power of two times a fixed block size.

When `c` and `d` are exactly one block in size,
the tree hash T() used in THEX is defined something like

```
T(c) == SHA1( 0x01 || c ) # only for 'c' exactly 1 block long
T(d) == SHA1( 0x01 || d ) # only for 'd' exactly 1 block long
T( c || d ) == SHA1( 0x00 || T(c) || T(d) )
            == SHA1( 0x00 || SHA1( 0x01 || c ) || SHA1( 0x01 || d ) )
```

Typically a block has a size of 1024 bytes; Dan Williams and Emin G¨un Sirer have written a paper on [picking an optimal block size](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/egs/papers/hashtree.pdf).

There are apparently two common ways to avoid the easy collisions described by
" [What is the purpose of using different hash functions for the leaves and internals of a hash tree?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2106/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-different-hash-functions-for-the-leaves-and-interna) ":

- some Merkle trees -- such as the THEX described above -- use one hash function for the leaves, and a different hash function for the internal nodes.
- Other Merkle trees -- such as the one used by BitTorrent -- keep track of both the file length and the root SHA1 hash value, and files are considered "the same" only if *both* match. This allows them to use the same unmodified SHA1 hash function for both the leaves and the internal nodes. (Some people think of this as a single "tree hash value" that includes two parts, the file length and the cryptographic hash value).

Merkle trees can handle files with size that is not a power of two --
[How does a "Tiger Tree Hash" handle data whose size isn't a power of two?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/how-does-a-tiger-tree-hash-handle-data-whose-size-isnt-a-power-of-two) --
but if the first file isn't a power of two times the fixed block size, concatenating 2 files doesn't give the nice relationship you wanted between the hash of the two smaller files and the hash of the bigger combined file.